# Blazor How do I merge a JSON to update MongoDB relation based on input

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, linq, blazor

***Note: Sorry in advance, this is my first question here!***

I'm currently developing a simplistic app using Blazor. I've setup a mongoDB database with associated collections titled team and teamMembers. I've created models, services, and controllers to handle the database requests. The .razor component has an input form to add teams, which works as intended. I wanted to take it a step further and add associated team members. I'm able to successfully post the new team members to the teamMembers collection in the MongoDB database; however, I can't figure out how to do a PUT request to the team collection to include the teamMembers nested within the team.

I'm still relatively new to C# and the ASP.NET framework am having trouble taking input related to the teamMembers and adding it to the team collection.

**Models**:
**Team.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Dashboard.Shared.Models
{
    public class Team
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public List<string> TeamMembers { get; set; }

        [BsonIgnore]
        public List<TeamMember> TeamMemberList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**TeamMember.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace Dashboard.Shared.Models
{
    public class TeamMember
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Rank { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Services:**
**TeamService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using Dashboard.Shared.Models;

namespace Dashboard.Server.Services
{
    public class TeamService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<Team> _teams;
        public TeamService(IDashboardDatabaseSettings settings)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);
            _teams = database.GetCollection<Team>(settings.TeamsCollectionName);
        }

        public async Task<List<Team>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await _teams.Find(s => true).ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task<Team> GetByIdAsync(string id)
        {
            return await _teams.Find<Team>(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
        public async Task<Team> CreateAsync(Team team)
        {
            await _teams.InsertOneAsync(team);
            return team;
        }
        public async Task UpdateAsync(string id, Team team)
        {
            await _teams.ReplaceOneAsync(s => s.Id == id, team);
        }
        public async Task DeleteAsync(string id)
        {
            await _teams.DeleteOneAsync(s => s.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

**TeamMemberService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using Dashboard.Shared.Models;

namespace Dashboard.Server.Services
{
    public class TeamMemberService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<TeamMember> _teamMembers;
        public TeamMemberService(IDashboardDatabaseSettings settings)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);
            _teamMembers = database.GetCollection<TeamMember>(settings.TeamMembersCollectionName);
        }

        public async Task<List<TeamMember>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await _teamMembers.Find(c => true).ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task<TeamMember> GetByIdAsync(string id)
        {
            return await _teamMembers.Find<TeamMember>(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
        public async Task<TeamMember> CreateAsync(TeamMember teamMember)
        {
            await _teamMembers.InsertOneAsync(teamMember);
            return teamMember;
        }
        public async Task UpdateAsync(string id, TeamMember teamMember)
        {
            await _teamMembers.ReplaceOneAsync(c => c.Id == id, teamMember);
        }
        public async Task DeleteAsync(string id)
        {
            await _teamMembers.DeleteOneAsync(c => c.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controllers:**
**TeamController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Dashboard.Server.Services;
using Dashboard.Shared.Models;

namespace Dashboard.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TeamController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly TeamService _teamService;
        private readonly TeamMemberService _teamMemberService;
        public TeamController(TeamService service, TeamMemberService tService)
        {
            _teamService = service;
            _teamMemberService = tService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Team>>> GetAll()
        {
            var teams = await _teamService.GetAllAsync();
            return Ok(teams);
        }


        [HttpGet("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Team>> GetById(string id)
        {
            var team = await _teamService.GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (team == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (team.TeamMembers != null)
            {
                if (team.TeamMembers.Count > 0)
                {
                    var tempList = new List<TeamMember>();
                    foreach (var teamMemberId in team.TeamMembers)
                    {
                        var teamMember = await _teamMemberService.GetByIdAsync(teamMemberId);
                        if (teamMember != null)
                            tempList.Add(teamMember);
                    }
                    team.TeamMemberList = tempList;
                }
            }
            return Ok(team);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Team team)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            await _teamService.CreateAsync(team);
            return Ok(team);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, Team updatedTeam)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var queriedTeam = await _teamService.GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (queriedTeam == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            await _teamService.UpdateAsync(id, updatedTeam);
            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
        {
            var team = await _teamService.GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (team == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            await _teamService.DeleteAsync(id);
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
}
```

**TeamMemberController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Dashboard.Server.Services;
using Dashboard.Shared.Models;

namespace Dashboard.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TeamMemberController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TeamMemberService _teamMemberService;
        public TeamMemberController(TeamMemberService tService)
        {
            _teamMemberService = tService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TeamMember>>> GetAll()
        {
            var teamMembers = await _teamMemberService.GetAllAsync();
            return Ok(teamMembers);
        }


        [HttpGet("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TeamMember>> GetById(string id)
        {
            var teamMember = await _teamMemberService.GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (teamMember == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(teamMember);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(TeamMember teamMember)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            await _teamMemberService.CreateAsync(teamMember);
            return Ok(teamMember);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, TeamMember updatedTeamMember)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var queriedTeamMember = await _teamMemberService.GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (queriedTeamMember == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            await _teamMemberService.UpdateAsync(id, updatedTeamMember);
            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
        {
            var teamMember = await _teamMemberService.GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (teamMember == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            await _teamMemberService.DeleteAsync(id);
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs (Just related services)**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            services.AddScoped<TeamService>();
            services.AddScoped<TeamMemberService>();
            ...

        }
```

**TeamFetch.razor**

```
@page "/addteam"
@using System.Net.Http
@using Dashboard.Shared.Models
@inject HttpClient Http


<MatH5>Add Teams</MatH5>
<br />
<div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@this.AddTeam">Add Teams</button>
    </div>

</div>
<br />

@if (teamList == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var team in teamList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@team.Name</td>
                    <td>@team.Location</td>
                    <td>@team.Type</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@this.AddTeamMember">Add Members</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-info" @onclick="@(async () => await EditTeam(team.Id))">Edit</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(async () => await DeleteConfirm(team.Id))">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    if (isAddMember)
    {
        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display:block" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title">@modalTitle</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="close" @onclick="@this.closeModal">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">X</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                                <input for="Name" class="form-control" @bind=teamMember.Name />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Position" class="control-label">Position</label>
                                <input asp-for="Position" class="form-control" @bind=teamMember.Rank />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Role" class="control-label">Role</label>
                                <select asp-for="Role" class="form-control" @bind=teamMember.Role>
                                    <option value="">-- Select Team Type --</option>
                                    <option value="Team Leader">Team Leader</option>
                                    <option value="Team Member">Team Member</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-block btn-success" @onclick="@(async () => await SaveTeamMember(team.Id))" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    if (isAdd)
    {
        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display:block" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title">@modalTitle</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="close" @onclick="@this.closeModal">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">X</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                                <input for="Name" class="form-control" @bind=team.Name />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Location" class="control-label">Location</label>
                                <input asp-for="Location" class="form-control" @bind=team.Location />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label">Type</label>
                                <select asp-for="Type" class="form-control" @bind=team.Type>
                                    <option value="">-- Select Team Type --</option>
                                    <option value="Ops">Ops</option>
                                    <option value="Tech">Tech</option>
                                    <option value="Staff/Management">Staff / Management</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-block btn-success" @onclick="@(async () => await SaveTeam())" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    if (isDelete)
    {
        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display:block" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title">Delete Team</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h4>Do you want to delete this team??</h4>
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>@team.Name</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Location</td>
                                <td>@team.Location</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Type</td>
                                <td>@team.Type</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(async () => await DeleteTeam(@team.Id))" data-dismiss="modal">YES</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" @onclick="@this.closeModal">NO</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

@code {

    private List<Team> teamList;
    private Team team = new Team();
    private List<TeamMember> teamMemberList;
    private TeamMember teamMember = new TeamMember();

    private string modalTitle { get; set; }
    private Boolean isDelete = false;
    private Boolean isAdd = false;
    private Boolean isAddMember = false;

    private string SearchString { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetTeam();
        await GetTeamMember();
    }

    private async Task GetTeam()
    {
        teamList = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Team>>("api/team/");
    }

    private async Task GetTeamMember()
    {
        teamMemberList = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<TeamMember>>("api/teammember/");
    }

    private void AddTeamMember()
    {
        teamMember = new TeamMember();
        this.modalTitle = "Add Team Member";
        this.isAddMember = true;
    }

    private void AddTeam()
    {
        team = new Team();
        this.modalTitle = "Add Team";
        this.isAdd = true;
    }

    private async Task EditTeam(string id)
    {
        team = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Team>("api/team/" + id);
        this.modalTitle = "Edit Team";
        this.isAdd = true;
    }

    private async Task SaveTeam()
    {
        if (team.Id != null)
        {
            await Http.PutAsJsonAsync<Team>($"api/team/{team.Id}", team);
        }
        else
        {
            await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<Team>("api/team/", team);

        }
        this.isAdd = false;
        await GetTeamMember();
    }

    /*THIS IS WHERE I'M NOT SURE WHAT TO DO*/
    private async Task SaveTeamMember(string id)
    {
        if (teamMember.Id != null)
        {
            await Http.PutAsJsonAsync<TeamMember>($"api/teammember/{teamMember.Id}", teamMember);
        }
        else
        {
            await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<TeamMember>("api/teammember/", teamMember);

        }
        this.isAddMember = false;

        await GetTeam();
    }

    private async Task DeleteConfirm(string Id)
    {
        team = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Team>("api/team/" + Id);
        this.isDelete = true;
    }

    private async Task DeleteTeam(string Id)
    {
        await Http.DeleteAsync("api/team/" + Id);
        this.isDelete = false;
        await GetTeam();
    }

    private void closeModal()
    {
        this.isAdd = false;
        this.isDelete = false;
    }
}
```

**Edit 1: **
I forgot to put the JSON output from the form input

**Team.Json**

```
{
    "id": "5fcdc04f126ca946e44a257b",
    "name": "Team 2",
    "location": "Office Building 3",
    "type": "Staff/Management",
    "teamMembers": null,
    "teamMemberList": null
}
```

**TeamMember.Json**

```
{
   "id": "5fcd816d8275e9e054e54ac7",
   "name": "John Smith",
   "rank": "Tech Lead",
   "role": "Team Leader"
}
```

My question is how do I construct a PUT request where I can nest the created Team Member mongoDB object ID into the "teamMembers" list in the Team.Json to create the relation? I can do them individually, but can't figure out the code to merge them when the team member is created.

I can manually do that in PostMan and I get the expected return result

**Expected Return**

```
{
    "id": "5fcdc04f126ca946e44a257b",
    "name": "Team 2",
    "location": "Office Building 3",
    "type": "Staff/Management",
    "teamMembers": [
        "5fcd816d8275e9e054e54ac7"
    ],
    "teamMemberList": [
        {
            "id": "5fcd816d8275e9e054e54ac7",
            "name": "John Smith",
            "rank": "SGT",
            "role": "Team Leader"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Update**

I was able to successfully fix some of my code to take the input and merge the team and teamMembers input; however, I'm now at a new issue.

If there are no teamMembers that have been added to the team yet, then I can successfully construct the needed JSON to add a singular teamMember to the team; however, if teamMembers already exist in the team, I'm struggling to develop the code to add the new teamMember to the existing teamMembers. I'll place the updated code below to help better explain my new question

**Updated TeamFetch.razor**

```
    private async Task SaveTeamMember(string teamid)
    {
        if (teamMember.Id != null)
        {
            await Http.PutAsJsonAsync<TeamMember>($"api/teammember/{teamMember.Id}", teamMember);
        }
        else
        {
            var postTeam = teamMember;
            var postTeamRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/teammember")
            {
                Content = JsonContent.Create(postTeam)
            };

            var postTeamResponse = await Http.SendAsync(postTeamRequest);

            postTeamResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string postrespBody = await postTeamResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JObject memberpost = JObject.Parse(postrespBody);
            var memberid = memberpost["id"].ToString();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.GetAsync($"api/team/" + teamid);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JObject teamreturn = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
            var id = teamreturn["id"].ToString();
            var name = teamreturn["name"].ToString();
            var location = teamreturn["location"].ToString();
            var type = teamreturn["type"].ToString();
            var members = teamreturn["teamMembers"].ToString();

            if (members == "")
            {
                Team payload = new Team
                {
                    Id = id,
                    Name = name,
                    Location = location,
                    Type = type,
                    TeamMembers = new List<string> {
                        memberid
                        }
                };

                await Http.PutAsJsonAsync<Team>($"api/team/{teamid}", payload);

            }
            else
            {
                /*This is where I need assistance now*/
                Team payload = new Team
                {
                    Id = id,
                    Name = name,
                    Location = location,
                    Type = type,
                    TeamMembers = new List<string>{
                        members,
                        memberid
                        }
                };

                await Http.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/team/{teamid}", payload);

            }

        }
        this.isAddMember = false;

        await GetTeam();
    }
```

Above I placed a comment where I'm struggling. How do I add a single string into a variable that doesn't know it's a list until the get request is executed? Not sure if that's the right way to ask it, but that's where I'm stuck now, lol.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working to allow for me to merge the user input for both individual team members and when multiple team members existed already.

```
 private async Task SaveTeamMember(string teamid)
    {
        if (teamMember.Id != null)
        {
            await Http.PutAsJsonAsync<TeamMember>($"api/teammember/{teamMember.Id}", teamMember);
        }
        else
        {
            var postTeam = teamMember;
            var postTeamRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/teammember")
            {
                Content = JsonContent.Create(postTeam)
            };

            var postTeamResponse = await Http.SendAsync(postTeamRequest);

            postTeamResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string postrespBody = await postTeamResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JObject memberpost = JObject.Parse(postrespBody);
            var memberid = memberpost["id"].ToString();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.GetAsync($"api/team/" + teamid);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JObject teamreturn = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
            var id = teamreturn["id"].ToString();
            var name = teamreturn["name"].ToString();
            var location = teamreturn["location"].ToString();
            var type = teamreturn["type"].ToString();
            var members = teamreturn["teamMembers"].ToString();

            if (members == "")
            {
                Team payload = new Team
                {
                    Id = id,
                    Name = name,
                    Location = location,
                    Type = type,
                    TeamMembers = new List<string> {
                        memberid
                        }
                };

                await Http.PutAsJsonAsync<Team>($"api/team/{teamid}", payload);

            }
            else
            {
                List<string> newmembers = new List<string>();
                foreach (var member in teamreturn["teamMembers"])
                {
                    newmembers.Add(member.ToString());
                }
                newmembers.Add(memberid);

                Team payload = new Team
                {
                    Id = id,
                    Name = name,
                    Location = location,
                    Type = type,
                    TeamMembers = newmembers

                };

                await Http.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/team/{teamid}", payload);

            }

        }
        this.isAddMember = false;

        await GetTeamMember();
    }
```